Why Unity Vuforia is not building properly for android
I am trying to create simple android app with unity and vuforia. When I preview the app it works great locally. But when I build it for android it is not ok. It manages to find the astronaut example (even if it is not specified in the image target), but doesn't find the custom target. It is simple 3d cube. License key is added. The build profile is android and it is set to minimum os 8.0 oreo.
I tried everything I can think of. Importing the library from my assets or from the official package. Adding different targets. Different materials to the cube, sphere. Changing different build and player settings. But no results.

which Vuforia feature are you using? MultTargets or ModeTarget? A cube is unlikely to work as a model target. Please have a look at the information on this page https://developer.vuforia.com/library/model-targets/model-targets-supported-objects-cad-model-best-practices

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I managed to fixed it. In all tutorials they say only to modify the minimum API Level to Android 8 (currently). And they leave the target api level to highest. In my case when I specified Android 12, it installed some additional libraries and start working. Thanks for all comments.
